# CPLEX integration in Anylogic

Tags: cplex, anylogic

i'm trying to implement a simple optimization in a traffic simulation. Is there a way to include CPLEX into an Anylogic Simulation?

Comment: why can't you just usr the AnyLogic optimization experiment instead? Redefining your optimization problem there...

Answer (score 4):

CPLEX provides Java API, so all you need is to:

- install CPLEX;
- add CPLEX.jar to AnyLogic model dependencies. The file is included in CPLEX, e.g. at Windows the file location is something like: C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\cplex\lib\cplex.jar;
- add path to native libs to java.library.path through experiment properties, Java machine arguments;
- invoke CPLEX with his Java API directly from AnyLogic model.

[Here is example model](https://theanylogic-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/monakhov_anylogic_com/EU70EigkmqtFq1PwC3zNQdUBvE_1hgudb0uUeON8cRf6SQ?e=Qfm50k) that demonstrates how it works. It refers to cplex.jar and native libs in default location on Windows (CPLEX Studio IDE 20.1.0), you may need to adjust the path depending on your version and installation location.

BTW in similar way you may integrate Matlab and other tools with Java API.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a flat file with Anylogic and then use this as input for Cplex. You could also use Java since Anylogic has a Java API and same for Cplex.